# Get All Property of a specific class with one property of parent

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Please consider this codes:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ClassA PropA { get; set; }
}

class ClassC
{
    public ClassC()
    {
        var MyVar = new List<ClassA>
        {
            new ClassA()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Name1",
                PropA = new ClassA()
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    Name = "Name2",
                    PropA = new ClassA()
                    {
                        ID = 3,
                        Name = "Name3",
                        PropA = new ClassA()
                        {
                            ID =4,
                            Name = "Name4",
                            PropA = null,
                        }
                    }

                }
            },
            new ClassA()
            {
                ID = 5,
                Name = "Name5",
                PropA = new ClassA()
                {
                    ID = 6,
                    Name = "Name6",
                    PropA = null,
                }
            },
            new ClassA()
            {
                ID = 7,
                Name = "Name7",
                PropA = null,
            },
            new ClassA()
            {
                ID = 8,
                Name = "Name8",
                PropA = new ClassA()
                {
                    ID = 9,
                    Name = "Name9",
                    PropA = new ClassA()
                    {
                        ID = 10,
                        Name = "Name10",
                        PropA = new ClassA()
                        {
                            ID = 11,
                            Name = "Name11",
                            PropA = null,
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

I want to get All `ClassA` properties that aren't null and with name property of its parent. For example:

```
   Parent        Class A
--------------------------------
1)"Name1"     Class A with ID = 2
2)"Name2"     Class A with ID = 3
3)"Name3"     Class A with ID = 4
4)"Name5"     Class A with ID = 6
and...
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint: recursion will be the easiest way to handle this.

Comment: Honestly I don't like recursive functions and without recursio I haven't any idea for best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (C# 7):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Describe(ClassA a)
{
    var (parent, current) = (a, a.PropA);

    while (!(current is null))
    {
        yield return $"{parent.Name}     Class A with ID = {current.ID}";
        (parent, current) = (current, current.PropA);
    }
}
...
var results = MyVar.SelectMany(Describe);
```

As requested in a comment, C# 4 version:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> DescribeCSharp4(ClassA a)
{
    var parent = a;
    var current = a.PropA;

    while (current != null)
    {
        yield return parent.Name + "     Class A with ID = " + current.ID;

        parent = current;
        current = current.PropA;
    }
}
...
var results = MyVar.SelectMany(DescribeCSharp4);
```

Comment: You have a typo - method name should be `Describe`, not `Describe2` ;)

Comment: @RuiJarimba Yes indeed, just fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice solution BTW. You might need to specify that named tuples are available only from C# 7

Comment: @Arian this does what you need, is there anything you don't understand?

Comment: @RuiJarimba thanks, c# 7  tag is explicitly added to the question ;)

Comment: @Andrzej my bad, I didn't realize it :(

Comment: @Arian What do you mean? `var results = MyVar.SelectMany(Describe);` runs exactly on the list you create. (`MyVar`)

Comment: Thanks but C# 7 in my tags is a mistake. I want a solution on C# 4. I mean a solution without named tuple. Thanks again

Comment: @Arian I added C# 4 version

Comment: @Andrzej: Thanks for your solution. How I can get Dictionary<string, ClassA> from your code? `yield return` only works on `IEnumerable`